# Laravel - Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$username

Tags: laravel

I wrote a query to pass parameter from view to controller, and I got this error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$username

View Passing the parameter

```
<td width="25%"><a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('gamesListDetail',$game->id) }}">{{ $game->name }}</a></td>
```

Receiving Controller

```
    public function gamesListDetail($id = null)
    {
    $gamelists = DB::table("platform_games")
        ->select("platform_games.id", "platform_games.username","game_player.game_id")
        ->join("game_player","game_player.game_id","=","platform_games.id")
            ->where('platform_games.id',$id)
            ->take(5);
        return view('soccerrave.games.gamesListDetail', compact('gamelists'));
    }
```

Receiving View

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach($gamelists as $key => $gamelist)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>

                <td>{{ $gamelist->username }}</td>


            </tr>
        @endforeach
            <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                {{ $gamelists->links() }}
            </td>
            </tr>         
    </tbody>
```

I expect the view to display top 5 data based on the parameter. But I got this error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) says:

> **skip / take**
>
> To limit the number of results returned from the query, or to skip a
>   given number of results in the query, you may use the `skip` and `take`
>   methods:
>
> `$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();`

So by example we see that after `take` method there must be `get()` call.

So fix Your code:

```
public function gamesListDetail($id = null)
{
    $gamelists = DB::table("platform_games")
                     ->select(
                       "platform_games.id", 
                       "platform_games.username",
                       "game_player.game_id"
                     )
                     ->join(
                       "game_player",
                       "game_player.game_id", "=", "platform_games.id"
                     )
                     ->where('platform_games.id', $id)
                     ->take(5)
                     ->get(); // this one is required

    return view('soccerrave.games.gamesListDetail', compact('gamelists'));
}
```